# Minecraft error - says not downloaded

Tags: 64-bit, java, minecraft

When I try to run Minecraft (using JDK 6) it says login failed, not downloaded.

How do I rectify this? I don't know what to do and all the instructions say that the game should run right out of the launcher.

Comment: could be something wrong with the minecraft patch you have. Try downloading a fresh one from their website.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!